# python source code organization and __init.py__

Tags: python, package

I have a python source tree which is organised as follows:

```
>folder
   |-> utils
        |-> image.py
        |-> helper.py
        |-> __init__.py

   |-> core
        |-> vf.py
        |-> __init__.py
```

Now in vf.py, I have the following line to import utils

```
import utils
```

and subsequently I do something like:

```
img = utils.Image()
```

Now, if I leave the `__init__.py` file empty in the utils directory, this does not work and I get an error:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Image'
```

However, if I add the following line in `__init__.py` in the utils directory, it works:

```
from image import *
from helper import *
```

So, I am guessing that when the top level script is called it parses this `__init__.py` file and imports all the methods and classes from this utils package. However, I have a feeling this is not such a good idea because I am doing a * import and this might pollute the namespace.

So, I was wondering if someone can shed some light on the appropriate way to do this i.e. if I have parallel directories, what is a good way to import the classes from one python package to another (if indeed this `__init__.py` approach is not clean as I suspect).

Comment: I thought it was `__init__.py` not `__init.py__`.

Comment: Why guess how it works? Have you read the docs? https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using "img = utils.image.Image()"?
If the "Image" class is defined within the "image.py" file, I think this would work.

Answer (score 1):

When You're importing a module, the `__init__.py` file is executed. So, when You're writing `import utils`, Your code in `__init__.py` is called and `Image` class from image.py is imported.

For example, write the following code into `__init__.py`:

```
print("Hello, my utils module!")
```

(for testing only, ofc!)

and You will see this text when You'll execute Your program

Comment: P.S. and yes, importing `*` is not a good idea. Import just Image You need.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do something as:

```
from utils import image
img = image.Image()
```

Alternatively,

```
from utils.image import Image
img = Image()
```

and then I can leave a blank `__init__.py` file and it was fine.